# What are the advantages of having typed XML columns in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, xml, validation, xsd

From what I've read an XML column in SQL server can be typed (having a schema) or untyped. What are the advantages of using typed XML?

Is it just that the XML is validated?

Answer (score 1):

First is validation.

Second you can formulate XML queries based on the XSD and know that the XML content is compatible with your queries.

Answer (score 0):

It also helps with errors and debugging - see [Silent XQuery Failures](http://blogs.msdn.com/denisruc/archive/2007/04/19/silent-xquery-failures.aspx)